# How to run WMI commands on non-domain-joined server from script running using domain admin credentials

Tags: vbscript, active-directory, wmi, windows-server-2008-r2

I have a windows script running from a scheduled task, set to run with domain credentials.

It checks the disk space on all of my domain joined servers using WMI.

```
Set wmi = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & hostname & "\root\cimv2")
...

Set wmiresults = wmi.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_LogicalDisk WHERE Name = '" & _
    UCase(diskletter) & ":'")

For Each wmiresult In wmiresults
    ptotalspace = Round(CDbl(wmiresult.Size) / 1073741824, 2) 
    pfreespace = Round(CDbl(wmiresult.Freespace) / 1073741824, 2) 
Next
```

This script works fine for all domain joined servers.  But I need to include a non-domain-joined server into this checking, and it fails as the script lacks the necessary permissions on the target server.

I have tried the hacky method of creating a local user account with the same name and password as the domain admin acct, and adding it to local admins, but this didn't work.

Is there a way to allow the script permission to check the server's disks without joining it to the domain, and without having to create a duplicate or version of this script that runs using a local account with permission to perform this check?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is here: [Connecting to WMI Remotely with VBScript](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/wmisdk/connecting-to-wmi-remotely-with-vbscript)

Look at option 2 under the heading "To connect to a remote system using VBScript". You can use the [`SWbemLocator.ConnectServer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/wmisdk/swbemlocator-connectserver) method to pass different credentials to the connection. It looks like this:

```
strComputer = "Computer_B"
Set objSWbemLocator = CreateObject("WbemScripting.SWbemLocator")
Set objSWbemServices = objSWbemLocator.ConnectServer(strComputer, _
                                                     "Root\CIMv2", _
                                                     "fabrikam\administrator", _
                                                     "password")
```

Just replace "fabrikam\administrator" and "password" with a username and password that has permission on that machine. Then you can use that `objSWbemServices` object the same way you were using your `wmi` object.

That should work if you run it from a machine inside the domain too... I think. Give it a try.

Comment: Thankyou.  That works,  but I'm a bit weary of storing a server password in plaintext in a script so I may have to think about whether to use this in my situation.

Comment: I don't think you'll be able to get around that if you're running from a computer that's not joined to the domain. You have to send the credentials to the server somehow for them to be authenticated there, since the authentication can't happen on the local computer.